# Access file outside document root

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, root

I'm trying to write on a file that is outside the document root, which is `/var/www/html`.
The file I want to access is `/home/user/files/folder1/info.txt`, but my PHP file can't open it (it does even say that it doesn't exist, I checked it with `file_exists`).
I tried to chown the folder `/home/user/files` recursively (`chown -R apache /home/user/files`) and I also set the permissions to 777 on the info.txt file, but nothing seems to work.

I'm on CentOS and Apache2.

Answer (score 2):

From the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page:

> ```
>    SELinux policy for httpd can be setup to not allowed  to  access  users
>    home  directories.   If you want to allow access to users home directo-
>    ries you need to set the httpd_enable_homedirs boolean and  change  the
>    context of the files that you want people to access off the home dir.
>
>    setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
>    chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t ~user/public_html
> ```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with selinux, so the other poster may be on the right track, but this might help, too:

- Create a symlink from the file to the `/var/www/html/` directory
- Make sure The option `FollowSymLinks` is on -- you can do this in the main `httpd.conf` or in `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html` with this line:   `Options FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but your php might have been hardened within the `php.ini` file.  Look in your `php.ini` file for something like `open_basedir = /path/to/web/root`.

`open_basedir` limits all PHP file operations to the listed directory and below.